# iOS dev: How to change text in the textfield?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6

I'm a beginner trying to create my first app. I'm trying to get the user to enter in a number into the the textfield, the app does what it does, and then the answer gets placed into the textfield itself. I'm using the storyboard to make this.

For example:

User puts '1' into textfield, 'a' gets placed in place once the user presses enter.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change the `.text` property, for example:

```
self.textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@a", self.textField.text];
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Sorry if I'm misunderstanding. So in the implementation file I did:



`- (IBAction)changeField:(UITextField *)textField {
    self.textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@a", self.textField.text];
}`


And then on the storyboard I dragged the textfield into here, I think I'm misunderstanding as that didn't work.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I can't remember the specific action to hook up, but if you bind the text changed event to some method, and then change the text in that method, that should work.  What you've got looks fine to me (provided `changeField` is the right event, and it's hooked up right).

Answer (score 2):

If youy're simply passing the string then,

```
txtField.text = @"Hello"
```

and If you're getting text from UITextField then,

```
txtField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@a",txtField.text];
```

**txtField** is an outlet of UItextField

Answer (score 1):

Just go through some beginners guide and understand the concepts.
Please refer http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-uitextfield-uitextfielddelegate/ to get an idea of how to place UITextfield and adding events and all.